# nclass * nsamples in random forest is higher than the largest number supported by Integer type

Tags: random-forest, integer-overflow

I'm running random forest on a dataset with nsample = 20,379,102 and 5 features. The target feature is categorical with nclass = 107,189 levels. I receive the following error:

```
Error in integer(nclass * nsample) : vector size cannot be NA
Calls: randomForest ... randomForest.formula -> randomForest.default -> integer
In addition: Warning message:
In nclass * nsample : NAs produced by integer overflow
Execution halted
```

obviously nclass * nsamples in random forest source code is defined as integer which in my problem it is bigger than the largest number the Integer type supports.

I thought about training on several parts of data and combine the models, however the largset dataset that I could train on it contains nsample = 175,545 and nclass = 1257 which is very small portion of data.

Do you suggest any idea to fix the limitation of integer?

Comment: I am running the algorithm on a big cluster with large number of CPU nodes and memory. and I have tried both parallel and serial implementations which both are working very well with lower number of rows or class levels.